# handle url-redirects in asynchronous code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, grequests

Recently I decided to port a project from using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to using [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) to make asynchronous HTTP Requests instead for efficiency. One problem I face now
is that in my previous code, in cases where there was a redirect I could handle it using the following snippet:

```
req = requests.get('a domain')
if req.history:
    print req.url # that would be the last domain
```

In this way I could retrieve the last-visited url after the redirect.
So my question is if it's possible to achieve something similar with `grequests`. 
Reading the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests) I didn't manage to find a possible solution.
Thanks in advance!